# How to initialization Table Name use query builder in laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I tried initializing the table name but it got an error.

in this case, I gave initialization to 'a' & 'b' in the table name

So, This my code :

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
class Act_admin extends Model
{

    static function showCustomer(){

        $query = "a.CUST_CODE, a.CUST_NAME AS CUSTOMER NAME, a.GRADE";
        $data['data'] = DB::table("dummy_db.customer a ")
                            ->leftJoin("dummy_db.agents b", "a.AGENT_CODE", "=", "b.AGENT_CODE")                                                
                            ->select(DB::raw($query))->paginate(10);
        dd($data);
    }
}
```

a messages from the error :

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE [42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name 'customer a '
 (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `dummy_db`.`customer a ` inner join `dummy_db`.`agents b` on `a`.`AGENT_CODE` = `b`.`AGENT_CODE`)
```

Comment: you would use backticks `dummy_db.customer a` or try dummy_db.[customer a]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `as` to create alias.

```
$data['data'] = DB::table("dummy_db.customer as a")
                            ->leftJoin("dummy_db.agents as b", "a.AGENT_CODE", "=", "b.AGENT_CODE")                                                
                            ->select(DB::raw($query))->paginate(10);
```